# In RPL Multi preferred parent selection

Tags: c, contiki

In RPL (Routing protocol for low power and lossy networks) .If there is one node want to send data-packet to its parent and candidate parents. how we can select multi preferred parents instead of one preferred parent. how can i do this ?

kindly feed back plz..

Comment: Have you tried writing any code at all? At the current format, this question is not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Sir, kindly mention in which files i try to write code for this.